# Is there a way to emulate spacemacs's modeline with numbers to help jump between windows?

Tags: spacemacs, mode-line

I've been looking into rebuilding my config from scratch and used to use spacemacs. One thing I really liked was spacemacs's modeline that marked windows with a number and allows you to jump between windows with `<SPC> <number>`. Is there a package that replicates the modeline and shortcuts to switch between windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's [winum](https://github.com/deb0ch/emacs-winum).

---

I also switched from Spacemacs to my own configs, so if you're interested, you can refer [here](https://github.com/tshu-w/.emacs.d).